# how to retrieve data from the module and store the result in a variable nodejs

Tags: node.js, module

i have this code

```
        TinyURL.shorten(idvar , function(res) {
            console.log(res);     //Returns a shorter version of http://google.com
        })
```

for shortening url. i want the return value of res and store it in a variable so that i can use the result somewhere else.
I have used the

```
return res;
```

but it didn't help me out.
Is it related with promise?
If it is , than please explain that too.

Comment: Does `TinyURL.shorten` return a Promise? Or does it need to be callback?

Comment: @james It returns shorter version of the url, promise is mentioned nowhere

Comment: not what I meant, what do you see if you do `console.log(TinyURL.shorten(idvar))` (provide no callback)

Comment: I did the very same but it consoled out as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can "promisify" your `TinyURL.shortern` function e.g.

```
const shortenUrl = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  TinyURL.shorten(url, (err, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res))
);
```

Then you can make use of `async` / `await`

```
async someApi() {
  try {
    const shortened = await shortenUrl('http://google.com');
    console.log(shortened);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let shortenUrl;
    await TinyUrl.shorten(`${req.body.inputUrl}`).then((res) => {
        shortenUrl = res;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```